# How can I make a raster layer where each pixel is a value representing the minimum distance between that pixel and a value from another layer?

Tags: qgis, r, nlcd

For instance, say I have a raster map of open bodies of water where each point is 0 if it is not water or 1 if it is water.

How can I make a new layer where every point is the distance between that point and a 0 value in Layer 1?

I work in both R and QGIS.

Answer (score 3):

Use "Proximity (raster distance)":

[image]

Black is short distance, white is longer

[image]